# Assert a SoapUI test case with reason of failure

Tags: groovy, junit, soapui

I have a test case on which I want to put the assertion.

I need to provide a reason for failure in assertion.

My output from XML format is as follow:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>XYZ-001: input is wrong</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <con:fault xmlns:con="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context">
               <con:errorCode>XYZ-001</con:errorCode>
               <con:reason>input is wrong</con:reason>
               <con:location>
                  <con:node>PipelinePairNode1</con:node>
                  <con:pipeline>PipelinePairNode1_response</con:pipeline>
                  <con:stage>stage1</con:stage>
                  <con:path>response-pipeline</con:path>
               </con:location>
            </con:fault>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

My desired result should be the **faultstring** node of the xml.

For this I have tried with xpath assertion using this code:

```
declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace con='http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context';
boolean('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fault/')
```

and I put true as expected output. 
After generating JUnit report it was giving some other reason:

```
Cancelling due to failed test step

<h3><b>Failure Failed</b></h3><pre>[XPath Match] XPathContains comparison failed for path [declare namespace soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
declare namespace con='http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/context';
boolean('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fault/')], expecting [false], actual was [true]
</pre><hr/>
```

I then proceed with Groovy using following script:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def requsetHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.requestContent )
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
def refNum = responseHolder.getNodeValue("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fault/")
def testrunner = context.getTestRunner();
if (refNum != null){
    testrunner.fail("soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fault/faultstring")
}
```

but no luck this time time also.
junit failure reason was:

```
Cancelling due to failed test step

<h3><b>Failure Failed</b></h3><pre>[Script Assertion] net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: XPath syntax error at char 46 on line 2 in {...pe/soapenv:Body/soapenv:Fau...}:
 Unexpected token "<eof>" in path expression
</pre><hr/>
```

so is there any way by which i can generate my custom reason in junit output using assertion in either groovy or xpath.

Comment: looks you added `expecting [false]` instead of `true` in the `Xpath Assertion`, from your description?

Comment: No, the reason of failure of test case should be the reason mention in fault tag of xml. But here the reason is something different. Is there any way in which we can mention the custom error message in assert by using either of xpath or groovy.

Comment: Hmm., not clear. Do you want to add some more details with example?

Comment: After generating the junit report from soapui with assert, the report states the reason of failure aa expecting false, actual was true(as in 3 code in my question above). But instead of this message I want some other custom message like try again later. I hope that clears my point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question & comments, here is the `Script Assertion`.

- The script contains different ways how to show the customized message in the report.
- Please follow the in-line comments for details.
- Sample code snippet added for additional check for specific `errorCode` element value if the response is a `Fault`. You can apply it for other elements too.

**Script Assertion**:

```groovy
/**
 * The below script should be used as Script Assertion
 * which checks if the response contains Fault, raise error otherwise
 * Once it has fault in it, then it checks for the specific "errorCode", raise error with
 * customized message
 */

//Get the response parsed
def envelope = new XmlSlurper().parseText(context.response)

//There are three approaches to check & and throw customized error message
// if the response does not have Fault. Use one of them
assert envelope.Body.Fault, "Response does not have soap fault"
assert !envelope.Body.Fault.isEmpty(), "Response does not have soap fault"
if (!envelope.Body.Fault) { throw new Error ("Response does not have soap fault") }

//Further check for specific errorCode in the soap fault
def expectedErrorCode = 'XYZ-001'
def actualErrorCode = envelope.'**'.find {it.name() == 'errorCode' } as String

log.info "Actual code is : $actualErrorCode"
assert expectedErrorCode == actualErrorCode, "Soap fault should not have \"${expectedErrorCode}\""
```

You may quickly test it from [here](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5149214950555648) directly to see how it behaves if `errorCode` does not match.